# Why can you reverse list with foldl, but not with foldr in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

Why can you reverse a list with the foldl?

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' xs = foldl (\acc x-> x : acc) [] xs
```

But this one gives me a compile error.

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' xs = foldr (\acc x-> x : acc) [] xs
```

Error

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a]'
`a' is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for reverse' :: [a] -> [a] at foldl.hs:33:13
Relevant bindings include
x :: [a] (bound at foldl.hs:34:27)
acc :: [a] (bound at foldl.hs:34:23)
xs :: [a] (bound at foldl.hs:34:10)
reverse' :: [a] -> [a] (bound at foldl.hs:34:1)
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `x'
In the expression: x : acc
```

Comment: You should use `++` and wrap the `acc` in a list: `\acc x -> x ++ [acc]`. `foldr` type is `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, so the first argument is the "current element" you are considering (and not really the accumulator), and the second argument would contain the accumulator. It's probably best written as: `\x acc -> acc ++ [x]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a start, the type signatures don't line up:

```
foldl :: (o -> i -> o) -> o -> [i] -> o
foldr :: (i -> o -> o) -> o -> [i] -> o
```

So if you swap your argument names:

```
reverse' xs = foldr (\ x acc -> x : acc) [] xs
```

Now it compiles. It won't *work*, but it compiles now.

The thing is, `foldl`, works from left to right (i.e., backwards), whereas `foldr` works right to left (i.e., forwards). And that's kind of why `foldl` lets you reverse a list; it hands you stuff in reverse order.

Having said all that, you *can* do

```
reverse' xs = foldr (\ x acc -> acc ++ [x]) [] xs
```

It'll be *really slow*, however. (Quadratic complexity rather than linear complexity.)

Comment: You could get it to work in linear time with Hughes lists though (like showS)

Comment: You can use diff lists to efficiently reverse the list with `foldr`.

Answer (score 27):

**Every `foldl` is a `foldr`.**

Let's remember the definitions.

```
foldr :: (a -> s -> s) -> s -> [a] -> s
foldr f s []       = s
foldr f s (a : as) = f a (foldr f s as)
```

That's the standard issue one-step iterator for lists. I used to get my students to bang on the tables and chant "What do you do with the empty list? What do you do with `a : as`"? And that's how you figure out what `s` and `f` are, respectively.

If you think about what's happening, you see that `foldr` effectively computes a big composition of `f a` functions, then applies that composition to `s`.

```
foldr f s [1, 2, 3]
= f 1 . f 2 . f 3 . id $ s
```

Now, let's check out `foldl`

```
foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> t -> [a] -> t
foldl g t []       = t
foldl g t (a : as) = foldl g (g t a) as
```

That's also a one-step iteration over a list, but with an accumulator which changes as we go. Let's move it last, so that everything to the left of the list argument stays the same.

```
flip . foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> [a] -> t -> t
flip (foldl g) []       t = t
flip (foldl g) (a : as) t = flip (foldl g) as (g t a)
```

Now we can see the one-step iteration if we move the `=` one place leftward.

```
flip . foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> [a] -> t -> t
flip (foldl g) []       = \ t -> t
flip (foldl g) (a : as) = \ t -> flip (foldl g) as (g t a)
```

In each case, we compute *what we would do if we knew the accumulator*, abstracted with `\ t ->`. For `[]`, we would return `t`. For `a : as`, we would process the tail with `g t a` as the accumulator.

But now we can transform `flip (foldl g)` into a `foldr`. Abstract out the recursive call.

```
flip . foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> [a] -> t -> t
flip (foldl g) []       = \ t -> t
flip (foldl g) (a : as) = \ t -> s (g t a)
  where s = flip (foldl g) as
```

And now we're good to turn it into a `foldr` where type `s` is instantiated with `t -> t`.

```
flip . foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> [a] -> t -> t
flip (foldl g) = foldr (\ a s -> \ t -> s (g t a)) (\ t -> t)
```

So `s` says "what `as` would do with the accumulator" and we give back `\ t -> s (g t a)` which is "what `a : as` does with the accumulator". Flip back.

```
foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> t -> [a] -> t
foldl g = flip (foldr (\ a s -> \ t -> s (g t a)) (\ t -> t))
```

Eta-expand.

```
foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> t -> [a] -> t
foldl g t as = flip (foldr (\ a s -> \ t -> s (g t a)) (\ t -> t)) t as
```

Reduce the `flip`.

```
foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> t -> [a] -> t
foldl g t as = foldr (\ a s -> \ t -> s (g t a)) (\ t -> t) as t
```

So we compute "what we'd do if we knew the accumulator", and then we feed it the initial accumulator.

It's moderately instructive to golf that down a little. We can get rid of `\ t ->`.

```
foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> t -> [a] -> t
foldl g t as = foldr (\ a s -> s . (`g` a)) id as t
```

Now let me reverse that composition using `>>>` from `Control.Arrow`.

```
foldl :: (t -> a -> t) -> t -> [a] -> t
foldl g t as = foldr (\ a s -> (`g` a) >>> s) id as t
```

That is, `foldl` computes a big *reverse* composition. So, for example, given `[1,2,3]`, we get

```
foldr (\ a s -> (`g` a) >>> s) id [1,2,3] t
= ((`g` 1) >>> (`g` 2) >>> (`g` 3) >>> id) t
```

where the "pipeline" feeds its argument in from the left, so we get

```
((`g` 1) >>> (`g` 2) >>> (`g` 3) >>> id) t
= ((`g` 2) >>> (`g` 3) >>> id) (g t 1)
= ((`g` 3) >>> id) (g (g t 1) 2)
= id (g (g (g t 1) 2) 3)
= g (g (g t 1) 2) 3
```

and if you take `g = flip (:)` and `t = []` you get

```
flip (:) (flip (:) (flip (:) [] 1) 2) 3
= flip (:) (flip (:) (1 : []) 2) 3
= flip (:) (2 : 1 : []) 3
= 3 : 2 : 1 : []
= [3, 2, 1]
```

That is,

```
reverse as = foldr (\ a s -> (a :) >>> s) id as []
```

by instantiating the *general* transformation of `foldl` to `foldr`.

**For mathochists only.** Do `cabal install newtype` and import `Data.Monoid`, `Data.Foldable` and `Control.Newtype`. Add the tragically missing instance:

```
instance Newtype (Dual o) o where
  pack = Dual
  unpack = getDual
```

Observe that, on the one hand, we can implement `foldMap` by `foldr`

```
foldMap :: Monoid x => (a -> x) -> [a] -> x
foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
```

but also vice versa

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f = flip (ala' Endo foldMap f)
```

so that `foldr` accumulates in the monoid of composing endofunctions, but now to get `foldl`, we tell `foldMap` to work in the `Dual` monoid.

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl g = flip (ala' Endo (ala' Dual foldMap) (flip g))
```

What is `mappend` for `Dual (Endo b)`? Modulo wrapping, it's exactly the reverse composition, `>>>`.

Comment: Side note: the alternative [`newtype-generics` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics) _does_ provide [a `Newtype` instance for `Dual`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5.1/docs/Control-Newtype.html#t:Newtype)!

Answer (score 9):

You *can* use `foldr` to reverse a list efficiently (well, most of the time in GHC 7.9—it relies on some compiler optimizations), but it's a little weird:

```
reverse xs = foldr (\x k -> \acc -> k (x:acc)) id xs []
```

I wrote an explanation of how this works [on the Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative).

Answer (score 6):

`foldr` basically deconstructs a list, in the canonical way: `foldr f initial` is the same as a function with patterns:<sup>(this is basically the *definition* of foldr)</sup>

```
 ff [] = initial
 ff (x:xs) = f x $ ff xs
```

i.e. it *un-conses* the elements one by one and feeds them to `f`. Well, if all `f` does is cons them back again, then you get the list you originally had! (Another way to say that: `foldr (:) [] ≡ id`.

`foldl` "deconstructs" the list in inverse order, so if you cons back the elements you get the reverse list. To achieve the same result with `foldr`, you need to append to the "wrong" end – either as MathematicalOrchid showed, inefficiently with `++`, or by using a *difference list*:

```
reverse'' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse'' l = dl2list $ foldr (\x accDL -> accDL ++. (x:)) empty l

type DList a = [a]->[a]
(++.) :: DList a -> DList a -> DList a
(++.) = (.)
emptyDL :: DList a
emptyDL = id
dl2list :: DLList a -> [a]
dl2list = ($[])
```

Which can be compactly written as

```
reverse''' l = foldr (flip(.) . (:)) id l []
```

Comment: that's not sufficiently point-free :) `reverse'''' = foldr (flip(.) . (:)) id ``flip`` []`

Comment: @SassaNF: `reverse''''' = flip ($) [] . flip id id (flip id (flip (.) (:) $ flip fmap) foldr)`

Comment: I wonder, would `reverse''` be more performant with ``(++.) a b c = let z=b c in z `seq` a z`` ?

Answer (score 5):

This is what `foldl op acc` does with a list with, say, 6 elements:

```
(((((acc `op` x1) `op` x2) `op` x3) `op` x4) `op` x5 ) `op` x6
```

while `foldr op acc` does this:

```
x1 `op` (x2 `op` (x3 `op` (x4 `op` (x5 `op` (x6 `op` acc)))))
```

When you look at this, it becomes clear that if you want `foldl` to reverse the list, `op` should be a "stick the right operand to the beginning of the left operand" operator. Which is just `(:)` with arguments reversed, i.e.

```
reverse' = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

(this is the same as your version but using built-in functions).

When you want `foldr` to reverse the list, you need a "stick the left operand to the end of the right operand" operator. I don't know of a built-in function that does that; if you want you can write it as `flip (++) . return`.

```
reverse'' = foldr (flip (++) . return) []
```

or if you prefer to write it yourself

```
reverse'' = foldr (\x acc -> acc ++ [x]) []
```

This would be slow though.

Answer (score 3):

A slight but significant generalization of several of these answers is that you can implement `foldl` with `foldr`, which I think is a clearer way of explaining what's going on in them:

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap f = foldr step []
    where step a bs = f a : bs

-- To fold from the left, we:
--
-- 1. Map each list element to an *endomorphism* (a function from one
--    type to itself; in this case, the type is `b`);
--
-- 2. Take the "flipped" (left-to-right) composition of these
--    functions;
--
-- 3. Apply the resulting function to the `z` argument.
--
myfoldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myfoldl f z as = foldr (flip (.)) id (toEndos f as) z
    where
      toEndos :: (b -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b -> b]
      toEndos f = myMap (flip f)

myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse = myfoldl (flip (:)) []
```

For more explanation of the ideas here, I'd recommend reading Tom Ellis' ["What is `foldr` made of?"](http://web.jaguarpaw.co.uk/~tom/blog/posts/2012-11-04-what-is-foldr-made-of.html) and Brent Yorgey's ["`foldr` is made of monoids"](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/foldr-is-made-of-monoids/).