# Haskell-- Trying to make my foldl function work

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, tuples, foldleft

I have a function that converts [a, b, c, d, . . . ] to [(a,b), (c, d), . . .]. Now this works and here is the code for that:

```
makeTuple :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
makeTuple [] = []
makeTuple [a] = []
makeTuple (x:y:xs) = (x,y): (makeTuple xs)
```

Now the next thing I have to do is this: Using the previous function, convert each tuple to a product of its two elements, using foldl and a lambda expression. And this is what I have:

```
productTuple [x] = foldl makeTuple [] [x]
```

Now I am not sure if this is exactly what is being asked of me. I'm not sure if I should make a separate function with the type declaration and whatnot. Maybe someone can tell me if that is the best way to approach this. Also this code does not work, and I don't know why,I need help with this part. (notice that it says to use a lambda, but I have no idea how to really properly use those, which is another part I need help with) I  would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Who says you have to use your `makeTuple` function?

Comment: You probably have to implement the empty and cons case of productTuple, so `productTuple (x:xs)` and `productTuple []`.

Comment: Hint: how would you use `foldl` that takes as input a list, to recreate that list (so basically an `id` function)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26017352/67579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function should respect this signature :

```
 [a] -> (b,b) -> [a]
```

The accumulator has the type [a], the tuple has the type (b,b)

You can try a lambda like this `\acc (a, b) -> acc++[a*b]`

The final function could look like :

```
productTuple :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
productTuple xs = foldl (\acc (a, b) -> acc++[a*b]) [] (makeTuple xs)
```

You have some examples of [foldl function here](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldl_f.html)

[I tried this code here](https://eval.in/891701)

Answer (score -1):

The exercise is asking you to preprocess the input lists with the `makeTuple`, and then fold over it.

```
productTuple :: [Int] -> [Int]
productTuple xs = foldl (some lambda) something (makeTuple xs)
```

It is not the most convenient way to do it, but I guess that the point of the exercise is to force you to use `foldl` just for the sake of it.

Comment: Your use of OP's `makeTuple` leads to a type error: it only takes one list as an argument.